# Distributing Launch Agent and Application together for MAC OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, mac-app-store, daemons

I am trying to solve the following problem.

The application is aimed to provide customized backup for a phone connected through the USB. When the phone is connected to the system, the application should be launched.

I already wrote the components as follows. 
1. A Daemon that detects when the specific USB is connected and then launches the application.
2. The Application that performs the backup.

I need to bind these two things together. I went through the documentation for Launch Agents. But there are more about making the main backup application launch during login/logout or system startup/shutdown.

Can you please help me in solving this?

I really appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Kishore

Answer (score 1):

Add a launchd plist for your Daemon application to the /Library/LaunchDaemons directory

For more details on doing this refer:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html

or  Daemons section of 
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2083/_index.html